# Change PhantomJS proxy settings while running

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using Selenium and PhantomJs in a C#/Winforms application.
I have to set the proxy for PhantomJS before running it with this code:

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService("phantomjsdriver");

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.HttpProxy = string.Format("xx.xx.xx.xx:port");
driverService.ProxyType = "http";
driverService.Proxy = proxy.HttpProxy;
driverService.AddArgument(string.Format("--proxy-auth={0}:{1}", "username", "password"));

using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService))
{
//......
}
```

Now I have a list of proxies! And I need to change the proxy after each request, So what I do now is just quitting the driver then run it again with a new proxy.
It's not a very efficient way so I was wondering if there was any method to change the proxy without quitting the driver!
Thanks in advance!

*EDIT*
So there is a [function](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/11829) in PhantomJS that enable us to change the proxy at any time.

Any idea how to use it under Selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, After finding that PhantomJS has a setProxy function, It was just a matter of how to use it:

```
String script = "return phantom.setProxy(\"{0}\", {1}, \"http\", \"{2}\", \"{3}\")";
string func = string.Format(script, ppp.IP, ppp.Port, ppp.Username, ppp.Password);

Object obj = driver.ExecutePhantomJS(func);
```

Hope this code helps someone else!